# Regex to find numbers in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm using `removeNumbers` to remove all numbers in a given string with the regex
`"(^| )\\d+($|( \\d+)+($| )| )"`

Here's the code:

```
public class Regex {    
  private static String removeNumbers(String s) {
     s = s.trim();
     s = s.replaceAll(" +", " ");
     s = s.replaceAll("(^| )\\d+($|( \\d+)+($| )| )", " ");
     return s.trim();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] tests = new String[] {"123", "123 456 stack 789", "123 456 789 101112 131415 161718 192021", "stack 123 456 overflow 789 com", "stack 123 456 overflow 789", "123stack 456", "123 stack456overflow", "123 stack456", "123! @456#567"};
     for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        String test = tests[i];
        System.out.println("\"" + test + "\" => \"" + removeNumbers(test) + "\"");
     }  
  }    
}
```

**Output** :

```
"123" => ""
" 123 " => ""
"123 456 stack 789" => "stack"
"123 456 789 101112 131415 161718 192021" => ""
"stack 123 456 overflow 789 com" => "stack overflow com"
"stack 123 456 overflow 789" => "stack overflow"
"123stack 456" => "123stack"
"123 stack456overflow" => "stack456overflow"
"123 stack456" => "stack456"
"123! @456#567" => "123! @456#567"
```

Is there any better way to do this?

**Edit** :

As suggested by @mbomb007 in his previous answer, the regex `"( |^)[\\d ]+( |$)"` works as well:

```
private static String removeNumbers(String s) {
   s = s.trim();
   s = s.replaceAll(" +", " ");
   s = s.replaceAll("( |^)[\\d ]+( |$)", " ");
   return s.trim();
}
```

Comment: My answer was wrong, but now I fixed it. I posted a link to a web version running the regex against your test cases.

Comment: Is your output correct? If yes and you are looking for better way to rewrite your code than it looks like your question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Can strings in input start or end with spaces?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, they can.

Comment: Then it would be nice to add few cases explaining how your code should react on them.

Comment: @Pshemo Every string is trimmed using `trim()` at the beginning of `removeNumbers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIU, you can just do:

```
private static String removeNumbers(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();
}
```

`\b\d+\b` matches one or more digits that form a word.

**EDIT:**

Since the pattern must not match numbers in a string like `"123! @456#567"`, a combination of positive lookbehind and lookahead conditions can be used:

```
private static String removeNumbers(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?<= |^)\\d+(?= |$)", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();
}
```

Comment: Or all on one line `return s.replaceAll("\\d", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();`

Comment: This doesn't work for his example: `"123 stack456overflow" => "stack456overflow"`

Comment: I've added one more test case: `"123! @456#567" => "123! @456#567`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is a bit redundant (and also doesn't quite fit your test cases). You can use this:

```
"\\b[ ]*(?<![^\\d\\s])[\\d]+(?![^\\d\\s])[ ]*\\b"
```

The `\b` escape character represents a word border (start or end of a word). I also use `[ ]*` to ensure the spaces between numbers get removed. This regex also allows words to contain numbers without them getting replaced. Just like you want.

**EDIT**: I added a negative lookbehind and a positive lookahead.

`(?<![^\\d\\s])` - This ensures that the characters immediately preceding the digits are only more digits or spaces.

`(?![^\\d\\s])` - This ensures that the characters immediately following the digits are only more digits or spaces.

[**Try it here**](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cb%5B%20%5D*(%3F%3C!%5B%5E%5Cd%5Cs%5D)%5B%5Cd%5D%2B(%3F!%5B%5E%5Cd%5Cs%5D)%5B%20%5D*%5Cb&test_string=123%20%0A123%20456%20stack%20789%20%0Astack%0A123%20456%20789%20101112%20131415%20161718%20192021%0Astack%20123%20456%20overflow%20789%20com%0Astack%20overflow%20com%0Astack%20123%20456%20overflow%20789%20%0Astack%20overflow%0A123stack%20456%20%0A123stack%0A123%20stack456overflow%20%0Astack456overflow%0A123%20stack456%20%0A%20stack456%0A123!%20%40456%23567%20%0A%20123!%20%40456%23567&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) with your test cases. (Updated the hyperlink for added test case)

Comment: I've added one more test case: `"123! @456#567" => "123! @456#567`

Comment: @BharatKhatri I changed it for the added test case and updated the hyperlink to the new example. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: One of your earlier approaches using `"( |^)[\\d ]+( |$)"` works fine. I've added it in an edit to the question, since you've updated your answer and the earlier approach is no longer visible.

Comment: @BharatKhatri If it worked for you, good. It didn't work for all the test cases when I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with guava library:

```
 String text = "stack 123 456 overflow 789 com";
 String theLettersWithLargeSpaces = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.or(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE).retainFrom(text); 
 theLetters = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.collapseFrom(theLettersWithLargeSpaces , ' ');
 System.out.println(theLetters);
```

I assumed that not only digits can occur, but also other unwanted characters. The output would be: "stack overflow com"

CharMatcher is very powerful tool. I think that it is much more readable than regexes.

If you want just a function:

```
public String clearUnwantedChars(String text) {
      return CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.collapseFrom(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.or(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)
            .retainFrom(text), ' ');
}
```